# Log rotation on NginX in Configuration file

Tags: nginx, logging

I've tried [this](http://www.cambus.net/log-rotation-directly-within-nginx-configuration-file/) tutorial to rotate log file without external software, but it seems it doesn't work, my configuration on the `server {` block:

```
if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})") {}
access_log /var/log/access-$year-$month-$day.log;
error_log /var/log/error-$year-$month-$day.log;
```

and the file created, named:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 May 28 17:46 error-$year-$month-$day.log
```

my NginX version:

> nginx version: nginx/1.8.0
>
> built with OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015
>
> TLS SNI support enabled
>
> configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/nginx.lock --user=http --group=http --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=stderr --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/client-body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-imap --with-imap_ssl_module --with-ipv6 --with-pcre-jit --with-file-aio --with-http_dav_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_sub_module

Comment: Why do you want to do that instead of using log rotate?

Comment: I don't want to install another program..

Comment: @Kokizzu do you use containers for nginx?(docker/lxd)

Comment: logrotate comes pre-installed on many of the most common Linux distributions, and is pretty much a standard item which you usually want to be present.  If you want to avoid it, it's usually because you are operating in a minimal environment (e.g. embedded system or docker container), in which case you are probably better shipping the logs to something external to your system to manage.

Comment: @Navern no, I use standard archlinux without docker

Comment: @mc0e you're right.. i never use it before, it seems it preinstalled in archlinux too

Comment: @mc0e, yep, good comment:) if you use docker then it you can just volume /dev/log inside container. If not than you always have logrotate in your system.

Comment: logrotate is preinstalled. Moreover almost every service-daemon with custom logs have default logrotate configuration installed along binary package.

Answer (score 3):

According to that blog post,

> Please note, that it’s not possible to embed **variables in error_log** directives, as any potential error would not be able to be logged if the file cannot be written.

With that in mind, it is not possible to have the error log automatically rotated with the naming format `error-$year-$month-$day.log` using that Nginx method.

---

However, setting up log rotation for the error log is not very difficult. Create a simple shell (bash) script at `/usr/local/bin/rotate_nginx_error_log.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# /usr/local/bin/rotate_nginx_error_log.sh

# Get yesterday's date as YYYY-MM-DD
YESTERDAY=$(date -d 'yesterday' '+%Y-%m-%d') 

PID_FILE=/run/nginx.pid
LOG_FILE=/var/log/error.log
OLD_FILE=/var/log/error-$YESTERDAY.log

# Rotate yesterday's log.
mv $LOG_FILE $OLD_FILE

# Tell nginx to reopen the log file.
kill -USR1 $(cat $PID_FILE)
```

Make sure it has executable permissions:

```bash
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rotate_nginx_error_log.sh
```

Then add a cronjob to your crontab that rotates the log nightly at midnight:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/rotate_nginx_error_log.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

See my comment above, and cpburnz's reasoning, but if you really want to proceed:

You could write a script which writes just the log commands to an include file, with the current date hard-coded.  You'd have that `include`d into your nginx config file, and your script would restart or reload nginx after writing the log commands to the include file.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=`date -Id`

cat > /etc/nginx/includes/log_by_date.inc <<EOF
access_log /var/log/access-${date}.log;
error_log /var/log/error-${date}.log;
EOF

/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

You'd run that from cron, most likely close to midnight.

plus of course you need to `include /etc/nginx/includes/log_by_date.inc` where you have your current logging commands.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have on my server:

```
if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
    set $year $1;
    set $month $2;
    set $day $3;
}

access_log /path/to/logs/nginx-access-$year-$month.log;
```

Now, sometimes `$time_iso8601` has not the expected format, and the logs are then written in a file called `nginx-access--.log` (indeed, `$year` and `$month` are not set).

So I will think about changing the lines to something like this:

```
if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
    set $year $1;
    set $month $2;
    set $day $3;

    access_log /path/to/logs/nginx-access-$year-$month.log;
}
else {
    access_log /path/to/logs/nginx-access-notime.log;
}
```

However, as told by @cpburnz, you won't be able to do this for error logs.

Comment: This works great in windows but not in Linux (CentOS) - no access log file is written for some unknown reason.

Comment: Doesn't work in Debian as well.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for the access log with nginx 1.13.x

We wanted our access log config in the 'http' block, 'if' isn't allowed there so used 'map' instead:

```
http {
    ...

    # Variable for access log filename date
    map $time_iso8601 $logdate {
        '~^(?<ymd>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'   $ymd;
        default                         'nodate';
    }

    log_format    acfmt    '$remote_addr "$request" "$query_string" "$http_referer" $request_time $status';
    access_log    'logs/access_${logdate}.log'    acfmt;

    ...
}
```

Log rotation occurs on the first request each day. Contrary to documentation elsewhere, a SIGUSR1 does not seem to be required.